# What package puts text within " " into a `\texttt` format?

Tags: packages

I have a large .sty file with many packages, and I think one package within it is putting text within `""` marks into `\texttt` type format. That's pretty cool, and I would love to know *which* package is doing this, so that I can repeat the effect for documents which do not use that particular .sty file.

Which packages provide such a feature?

Comment: probably `\MakeShortVerb"` from the shortvrb package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{shortvrb}
\MakeShortVerb"

\begin{document}

   abc "abc"
\end{document}
```